# AIR: Load local xml files outside the application folder

Tags: apache-flex, security, air, local-files

I'm building an AIR application which will be used to edit slideshows for another app (also built by me, but not in AIR). The slideshows and other data are defined in several xml files which are in the other application's program folder. When trying to load these into my AIR app I get the following error:

```
fault(mx.messaging.messages::ErrorMessage)#0
  body = ""
  clientId = "DirectHTTPChannel0"
  correlationId = "D67CFDDA-2A2E-9D8B-21DE-7D9FB4B72167"
  destination = ""
  extendedData = (null)
  faultCode = "Server.Error.Request"
  faultDetail = "Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/Users/path/to/folder/languages.xml" errorID=2032]. URL: /Users/path/to/folder/languages.xml"
  faultString = "HTTP request error"
  headers = (Object)#1
    DSStatusCode = 0
  messageId = "F54EACC8-22F3-3718-9106-7D9FB4E0649C"
  rootCause = (flash.events::IOErrorEvent)#2
    bubbles = false
    cancelable = false
    currentTarget = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
      bytesLoaded = 0
      bytesTotal = 0
      data = ""
      dataFormat = "text"
  errorID = 2032
  eventPhase = 2
  target = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
  text = "Error #2032: Stream Error. URL:    app:/Users/path/to/folder/languages.xml"
  type = "ioError"
timestamp = 0
timeToLive = 0
```

This is how I've coded it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            this.languages.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, this.faultHandler);
            this.languages.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);

            this.languages.send();
        }

        private function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            trace("fault" + event.message);
        }

        private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            trace("success" + event.result);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:HTTPService id="languages" url="/Users/path/to/folder/languages.xml"/>
</fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

How can I read from these files? The app will have no need to communicate with anything but the local files.

Thanks to J_A_X's answer, I changed my creationCompleteHandler to:

```
var file:File = new File("/Users/path/to/folder/languages.xml");

var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var text:String = fs.readUTFBytes(file.size);
trace(text);
```

which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTPService is used for HTTP communication.  Getting a local file isn't HTTP.  You want to look at the [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class to open/read your xml.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I'm finding it weird though that I could easily use a HTTPService call to open an xml file in the bin folder, but not outside it. I wonder if I'm ever going to get my head around all of Flex/Flash's quirks...=)

Comment: That's different.  In the bin-debug it would work because it's going through the browser and the browser interprets it as an http call (even though it's a local file), but this changes if you're using Air. Not really a Flex quirk, more like a protocol quirk :P

Comment: So it's still like a http call even if it's not in the browser and just in the AIR app? Makes a bit more sense if so, thanks! =)